# Proper way to pull ASCII characters from a number

Tags: c++, ascii

I have created a small program to put whatever characters specified into ASCII and this works as expected.

The problem I am having is when trying to pull the characters from the ASCII number representation.

```
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    cout << "Enter your ASCII Message: ";
    cin >> a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    cout << "Unciphered Message: "  << char(a1) <<  char(a2) << char(a3) << char(a4) << char(a5) << endl;
```

I expected the above code to pull the proper character depending on the number specified, but it seems to only recognise the first character.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `cin >> a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;` to do? That line will simply do `cin >> a1`, but do nothing with `a2`, `a3`, `a4` or `a5`. See [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) for further information. Do you maybe mean `cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5;`?

Comment: You're a saint, I was wondering what my brain wasn't getting here... Thats what you get for learning to code with covid haha :) Cheers!

Comment: Instead of answering your own question inside the question itself, it would be more appropriate to post an answer to your own question. You may want to read this official help page: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Tactical note: When you find yourself making many sequentially named variables often the program will be easier to write with an array.

Answer (score 1):

I was improperly passing variables to `cin`. The line

`cin >> a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;`

should be replaced with:

`cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5;`